# Django admin page, user dropdown shows (None) when adding record, any idea?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two model, both of them inherit from `AbstractNonEntity`, like

```
class BR(AbstractNonEntity):
   ...

class MS(AbstractNonEntity):
   ...
```

And class `AbstractNonEntity` is defined like below

```
class AbstractNonEntity(GlobalIDMixin, CreatedOnMixin):

creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_created_objects',
                            verbose_name='Creator')
   ...
```

On admin page, when I add `BR` class, the `creator` show user drop-down, but when I add `MS` class, the `creator` only shows (*None*) and no drop-down.

Comment: Found there is a custom admin form

Comment: Interesting.  Just to sanity check: are you sure you applied all migrations, or to ask a different way... can you do python manage.py shell and in there do from foo.models import MS; MS.objects.create(...), and then if you edit that object, does it show the creator you assigned?